# Broken spark plug porcelain not letting easy out do its job

Tags: chevrolet, sparkplugs

[image] how do I get an easy out past porcelain easy out not grabbing and porcelain is not breaking

Comment: Only way I can see without removing the cylinder head it to break out the rest of the porcelain so you can use an easy out, bad part is some or all of it will fall into the cylinder.

Comment: If you can get the electrode out or if it came out you can stick a dowel in there with something to bond to the porcelain and extract it that way. Otherwise your going to have to break it up.

Comment: If you do get porcelain into the cylinder, you might be able to rotate the engine over to where the intake or exhaust valve is open (to get air flow), then put a small orifice attachment onto a shop vac and apply it to the spark plug hole. As long as you can get good air flow, you should be able to suck out any small bits/pieces of porcelain. I know this doesn't help you get the spark plug out, but may help you after the fact. I don't see anyway you are going to avoid getting some amount of porcelain into the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this exact problem on a Renault 5 many years ago and was able to get a flat blade screw driver down the remains of the sparkplug which butted up against the electrode tip and allowed me to turn the remaining part of the plug out without the hassle of removing the cylinder head.

If this doesn't work then it may be time to order a gasket set and set about splitting the engine I'm afraid.

Good luck.